# tabularx nor working properly in this journal format

Tags: tables, captions, tabularx, subcaption

Example is attached here, this is the example of very long table, Heading section is not working properly. Also, when I am increasing text in any cell, the table elongate vertically, and text goes outside the table.
Please help. Screenshot of output is also attached.[image]

```
    %% 
      %% Copyright 2019-2020 Elsevier Ltd
      %% 
    %% This file is part of the 'CAS Bundle'.
      %% --------------------------------------
    %% 
     %% It may be distributed under the conditions of the LaTeX Project Public
    %% License, either version 1.2 of this license or (at your option) any
  %% later version.  The latest version of this license is in
        %%    http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
     %% and version 1.2 or later is part of all distributions of LaTeX
     %% version 1999/12/01 or later.
       %% 
       %% The list of all files belonging to the 'CAS Bundle' is
   %% given in the file `manifest.txt'.
      %% 
        %% Template article for cas-dc documentclass for 
         %% double column output.

      %\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn,longmktitle]{cas-dc}
       \documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-dc}

       %\usepackage[authoryear,longnamesfirst]{natbib}
         %\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
      \usepackage[numbers]{natbib}


       \usepackage{textcomp}
   \usepackage{graphicx}
     % \usepackage{subfigure}
     % \usepackage{ftnxtra}
     \usepackage{subfig}
        \newcommand{\specialcell}[2][c]{%
      \begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}l@{}}#2\end{tabular}
              %%%
     }
       \usepackage[redeflists]{IEEEtrantools}
        \usepackage{caption}
         \usepackage{lipsum}
         \usepackage{tablefootnote}
        \usepackage{hyperref}
           \usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
          \usepackage{csquotes}
            \usepackage[demo,
        export]{adjustbox}
        \usepackage{stfloats}
         \usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}
        \usepackage{makecell, tabularx}   % changed
             \renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries}    % new
         \renewcommand\theadgape{}                   % new
              \setcellgapes{3pt}                          % new
        \usepackage{siunitx}

          \usepackage{enumitem}
             \usepackage{etoolbox}                       %
           \AtBeginEnvironment{tabularx}{%
         \setlist[itemize]{nosep,
             leftmargin=*,
             label=\textbullet,
             before=\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}, % <---
             after=\end{minipage}                    % <---
             }  }

            \usepackage{float}
             % \usepackage{enumitem}\setlist[description]{font=\textendash\enskip\scshape\bfseries}

          \usepackage{wrapfig}


           \begin{document}


            \begin{table*}[htbp]
          \scriptsize
          \setcellgapes{3pt}
         \makegapedcells
           \caption{caption).}  \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}    % <---               
         \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|@{} p{1.1cm}| p{1.5cm}| p{1.5cm}| p{3cm} |p{2cm}| X @{}|}

              \hline
         \thead{AAAAA}
              & \thead{BBBBBBBBB}
            & \thead{CCCCCCCCCC}
             & \thead{\specialcell{DDDDDDD} \\\ \specialcell{EEEEEE}}
        & \thead{\specialcell{FFFFFF} \\\ \specialcell{GGGGG}}
              & \thead{HHHHHHHH}                     \\
             \hline


           \multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{AAAAAAAAAAAA}} \\ 
          \hline

           \textbf{a}~\cite{x2} a & a \& bbbbbb &  bbbbbbb/ Live 1   & cccccccccccccc    & 
          \begin{itemize}
           \item dddddd
        \end{itemize}   & \begin{itemize}
        \item ddddddddddddd
        \item eeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
          \end{itemize} \\

           \hline

       \textbf{a}~\cite{x2} a & a \& bbbbbb &  bbbbbbb/ Live 1   & cccccccccccccc    & 
      \begin{itemize}
      \item dddddd
       \end{itemize}   & \begin{itemize}
      \item dddddddddddddddddddddddd
          \item eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
       \end{itemize} \\

          \hline

       \textbf{a}~\cite{x2} a & a \& bbbbbb &  bbbbbbb/ Live 1   & cccccccccccccc    & 
         \begin{itemize}
             \item dddddd
       \end{itemize}   & \begin{itemize}
          \item ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd
           \item eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
           \end{itemize} \\

        \hline


           \textbf{a}~\cite{x2} a & a \& bbbbbb &  bbbbbbb/ Live 1   & cccccccccccccc    & 
      \begin{itemize}
           \item dddddd
       \end{itemize}   & \begin{itemize}
        \item ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd
      \item eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
     \end{itemize} \\

      \hline


         \textbf{a}~\cite{x2} a & a \& bbbbbb &  bbbbbbb/ Live 1   & cccccccccccccc    & 
     \begin{itemize}
          \item dddddd
            \end{itemize}   & \begin{itemize}
          \item ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd
        \item eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeedeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
          \end{itemize} \\

     \hline


          \textbf{a}~\cite{x2} a & a \& bbbbbb &  bbbbbbb/ Live 1   & cccccccccccccc    & 
     \begin{itemize}
           \item dddddd
          \end{itemize}   & \begin{itemize}
            \item ddddddddddddd
            \item eeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
         \end{itemize} \\

         \hline

       \textbf{a}~\cite{x2} a & a \& bbbbbb &  bbbbbbb/ Live 1   & cccccccccccccc    & 
     \begin{itemize}
             \item dddddd
           \end{itemize}   & \begin{itemize}
         \item ddddddddddddd
          \item eeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
        \end{itemize} \\

         \hline


            \textbf{a}~\cite{x2} a & a \& bbbbbb &  bbbbbbb/ Live 1   & cccccccccccccc    & 
   \begin{itemize}
\item dddddd
      \end{itemize}   & \begin{itemize}
       \item ddddddddddddd
    \item eeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
       \end{itemize} \\

          \hline


      \textbf{a}~\cite{x2} a & a \& bbbbbb &  bbbbbbb/ Live 1   & cccccccccccccc    & \begin{itemize}
          \item dddddd
         \end{itemize}   & \begin{itemize}
        \item ddddddddddddd
         \item eeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
     \end{itemize} \\

           \hline


      \textbf{a}~\cite{x2} a & a \& bbbbbb &  bbbbbbb/ Live 1   & cccccccccccccc    & \begin{itemize}
\item dddddd
     \end{itemize}   & \begin{itemize}
      \item ddddddddddddd
     \item eeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
      \end{itemize} \\

         \hline


     \textbf{a}~\cite{x2} a & a \& bbbbbb &  bbbbbbb/ Live 1   & cccccccccccccc    & \begin{itemize}
        \item dddddd
      \end{itemize}   & \begin{itemize}
          \item ddddddddddddd
         \item eeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
       \end{itemize} \\

       \hline


            \textbf{a}~\cite{x2} a & a \& bbbbbb &  bbbbbbb/ Live 1   & cccccccccccccc    & 
         \begin{itemize}
           \item dddddd
           \end{itemize}   & \begin{itemize}
          \item ddddddddddddd
             \item eeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
             \end{itemize} \\

      \hline


         \textbf{a}~\cite{x2} a & a \& bbbbbb &  bbbbbbb/ Live 1   & cccccccccccccc    & 
       \begin{itemize}
                 \item dddddd
         \end{itemize}   & \begin{itemize}
         \item ddddddddddddd
         \item eeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
         \end{itemize} \\

      \hline


                   \textbf{a}~\cite{x2} a & a \& bbbbbb &  bbbbbbb/ Live 1   & cccccccccccccc    & 
        \begin{itemize}
             \item dddddd
          \end{itemize}   & \begin{itemize}
         \item ddddddddddddd
          \item eeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
         \end{itemize} \\

        \hline

       \textbf{a}~\cite{x2} a & a \& bbbbbb &  bbbbbbb/ Live 1   & cccccccccccccc    & 
          \begin{itemize}
            \item dddddd
          \end{itemize}   & \begin{itemize}
          \item ddddddddddddd
         \item eeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
           \end{itemize} \\

         \hline

      \textbf{a}~\cite{x2} a & a \& bbbbbb &  bbbbbbb/ Live 1   & cccccccccccccc    & \begin{itemize}
               \item dddddd
        \end{itemize}   & \begin{itemize}
       \item ddddddddddddd
     \item eeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
     \end{itemize} \\

       \hline

       \textbf{a}~\cite{x2} a & a \& bbbbbb &  bbbbbbb/ Live 1   & cccccccccccccc    & 
    \begin{itemize}
       \item dddddd
         \end{itemize}   & \begin{itemize}
         \item ddddddddddddd
        \item eeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
          \end{itemize} \\

       \hline

     \textbf{a}~\cite{x2} a & a \& bbbbbb &  bbbbbbb/ Live 1   & cccccccccccccc    & \begin{itemize}
       \item dddddd
        \end{itemize}   & \begin{itemize}
        \item ddddddddddddd
       \item eeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
      \end{itemize} \\

       \hline

        \textbf{a}~\cite{x2} a & a \& bbbbbb &  bbbbbbb/ Live 1   & cccccccccccccc    & 
       \begin{itemize}
        \item dddddd
        \end{itemize}   & \begin{itemize}
       \item ddddddddddddd
      \item eeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
     \end{itemize} \\

         \hline

     \textbf{a}~\cite{x2} a & a \& bbbbbb &  bbbbbbb/ Live 1   & cccccccccccccc    & \begin{itemize}
        \item dddddd
    \end{itemize}   & \begin{itemize}
        \item ddddddddddddd
          \item eeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
       \end{itemize} \\

        \hline

       \textbf{a}~\cite{x2} a & a \& bbbbbb &  bbbbbbb/ Live 1   & cccccccccccccc    & 
      \begin{itemize}
         \item dddddd
       \end{itemize}   & \begin{itemize}
             \item ddddddddddddd
      \item eeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
         \end{itemize} \\

         \hline
        \textbf{a}~\cite{x2} a & a \& bbbbbb &  bbbbbbb/ Live 1   & cccccccccccccc    & 
     \begin{itemize}
       \item dddddd
       \end{itemize}   & \begin{itemize}
       \item ddddddddddddd
        \item eeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
      \end{itemize} \\



        \hline



             \multicolumn{6}{r}{\textit{Continued on the next page}} \\
          \end{tabularx}
        \end{minipage}
        \end{table*}
          \begin{table*}[htbp]
           \ContinuedFloat
          \scriptsize
     \setcellgapes{3pt}
        \makegapedcells
       \caption[]{-- \textit{Continued from previous page}}
       \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}    % <---
   \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|@{} p{1.1cm}| p{1.5cm}| p{1.5cm}| p{3cm} |p{2cm}| X @{}|}

             \hline
    \thead{AAAAA}
       & \thead{BBBBBBBBB}
          & \thead{CCCCCCCCCC}
       & \thead{\specialcell{DDDDDDD} \\\ \specialcell{EEEEEE}}
        & \thead{\specialcell{FFFFFF} \\\ \specialcell{GGGGG}}
     & \thead{HHHHHHHH}                     \\
         \hline


            \textbf{a}~\cite{x2} a & a \& bbbbbb &  bbbbbbb/ Live 1   & cccccccccccccc    & 
       \begin{itemize}
     \item dddddd
     \end{itemize}   & \begin{itemize}
        \item ddddddddddddd
       \item eeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
      \end{itemize} \\

     \hline

     \textbf{a}~\cite{x2} a & a \& bbbbbb &  bbbbbbb/ Live 1   & cccccccccccccc    & \begin{itemize}
           \item dddddd
      \end{itemize}   & \begin{itemize}
         \item ddddddddddddd
       \item eeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
     \end{itemize} \\

         \hline

             \textbf{a}~\cite{x2} a & a \& bbbbbb &  bbbbbbb/ Live 1   & cccccccccccccc    & 
        \begin{itemize}
 \item dddddd
  \end{itemize}   & \begin{itemize}
  \item ddddddddddddd
    \item eeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
  \end{itemize} \\

    \hline
    \textbf{a}~\cite{x2} a & a \& bbbbbb &  bbbbbbb/ Live 1   & cccccccccccccc    & \begin{itemize}
       \item dddddd
      \end{itemize}   & \begin{itemize}
   \item ddddddddddddd
     \item eeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
   \end{itemize} \\

    \hline



       \end{tabularx}
      \end{minipage}
      \label{tablossy}
   \end{table*}

   \end{document}
```

Comment: Is this example really minimal?

Comment: can you try to show the problem with a standard class such as `\documentclass{article}` if that is possible it makes it much easier for people to try to help you.

Comment: It is not even compilable. Please edit your question providin an actual [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: What's the reason for the `minipage`?

Comment: your table has 6 columns but for example your first row only has 4 entries  `\thead{AAAAA}
              & \thead{BBBBBBBBB}
            & \thead{CCCCCCCCCC}
             & \thead{\specialcell{DDDDDDD} \\ `which produces the image you show with only 4 cells.  perhaps just add `&&` before the `\\ `

Comment: exactly, my table has 6 column, but if you see at the top, the headings of those 6 columns are not arranged in a proper manner. I have shown long table, to make the solution compatible for more than one page. And the same output is working as it is in the sanpshot

Comment: we can not run your code, just take the tabularx example and place it in a simple article document to demonstrate the problem, but as I say you have 6 columns but only supplied 4 headings so the row is forced to be short. Tabularx is working properly, it can only add headings if you supply them.